# How to make use of dom4j.jar and jaxen.jar to GWT project client side?

Tags: gwt, jar, client, external

I am new to Java and GWT.

I want to make use of dom4j and jaxen to parse a xml file and construct the webpage according 
to the xml file content.

However, the compile fail and the error is listed below:

```
[ERROR] [MainPage] - Errors in 'file:/E:/workspace/MainPage/src/com/helloworld/client/MainPage.java'
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 10: The import org.dom4j cannot be resolved
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 81: The type org.dom4j.DocumentException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 81: The constructor DataModelReader(File, SmfDataPositionAgent) refers to the missing type DocumentException
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 82: DocumentException cannot be resolved to a type
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 87: The method navigatePageSet() from the type DataModelReader refers to the missing type DocumentException
    [ERROR] [MainPage] - Line 88: DocumentException cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use dom4j on client side as it is not a GWT module. Maybe you should consider using GWTs XML parser:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html

Or you can try with this project, I haven't try it though.

https://code.google.com/p/dom4j4gwt/